# Jquery data returns undefined in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have created a fileupload function which works great in chrome, firefox, ie10 and ie11.

But in ie9 I can't get the file that gets uploaded.

Code that gets the file:

```
var files = $('.browseOption input[type=file]').data('files');
```

Files is always undefined for some reason.
I also noticed that the url for the upload was `C:\fakepath\test.csv`

To fix this I changed the IE settings to "Include local directory path When uploading files to a server"

But the script problem remains

**HTML**

```
<div class="browseOption"> <span><input value="Bläddra" type="button" class="button" /></span> 
    <input type="text" class="uploadFile" placeholder="Välj en bildfil" readonly/>
    <input type="file" name="Person.UploadedImg" class="upload hidden" />
</div>
```

Im trying not to show unnecessary code here but if you need more or if i am unclear just ask.

Thanks!

Comment: what jquery library you have used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see why `.data('files')` would work in any browser (`.prop('files')` would, in the ones that support the File API).

But the fundamental issue is that IE9 [doesn't support the File API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi). The `files` property on `input[type=file]` is part of the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). IE didn't get support for it until IE10.

Comment: @Ra3IDeN: No, it wouldn't. Again: IE9 doesn't support the File API.

Comment: sorry i misunderstood ur answer, so there is no possible way to come arround this?

Comment: I was hoping there might come an answer i would like more here but I assume that im hoping for something that simply is not possible. Thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: @Ra3IDeN: It depends on what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to do much of *anything* with the file client-side, no, there's no JavaScript way to overcome it. There are Flash or Java applet options, but the user would have to grant security permissions.